# AngularJS: How to pass button clicked ng-model value from one controller to another controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a button where I am passing the ng-model value as a parameter to its ng-click function, Now after this ng-click function executes, I would like to send that ng-model value to another controller, how can I do this using angular?

> Is there a way to do this?

Comment: $broadcast should work !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$on and $broadcast in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular)

Comment: You can use $broadcast, $rootScooe, services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to communicate between controllers.

1. use $broadcast like mentioned in other comments, or
2. use $emit

Something like this...

```
function Controller1($scope) 
{
    $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, args) {
        // do the event
    });
  // another controller, directive
}

function Controller2($scope) 
{
  $scope.$emit('myEvent', args);
}
```

Comment: broadcast dispatches everything down while emit dispatches upwards through hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

1.In first Controller, you can do:

**$rootScope.$broadcast('eventName', value);**

and listen to the event in second Controller:

**$scope.$on('eventName', function (event, value) {//your code});**

2.In first controller assign the values to the $rootScope variable then access from the other controller.for example
in first controller

**$rootScope.TestValue="10";**

in second controller

**$scope.receiveValue=$rootScope.TestValue;**

3.[AngularJS- How to pass data from one controller to another on ng-click()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222348/angularjs-how-to-pass-data-from-one-controller-to-another-on-ng-click?rq=1)

Answer (score -2):

Use angular service to communicate between 2 controller.
Watch this [Video](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/)

Yes $broadcast will work for you.

Here are some essential parts:

1. Create service that implements message bus functionality (e.g. `$scope` instance)
2. Inject service to both controllers
3. `$broadcast()` event from one controller
4. subscribe to event with `$on()` in another

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1 as ctrl1">
  <button ng-click="ctrl1.hello()">Say hello</button>
</div>
<div ng-controller="ctrl2 as ctrl2">{{ctrl2.messages}}</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.service('messageBus', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return $rootScope.$new();
}])
.controller('ctrl1', ['messageBus', function(messageBus) {
  this.hello = function() {
    messageBus.$broadcast('hello', 'Hi! '); // <= send message
  }
}])
.controller('ctrl2', ['messageBus', function(messageBus) {
  var ctrl2 = this;
  this.messages = '';
  console.log(messageBus.mb)
  messageBus.$on('hello', function(evt, msg) { // <= receive message
    ctrl2.messages += msg;
  });
}]);
```